# Searching for word with lower case and upper case in regex

Tags: regex

I have started using regex and am trying to write an expression which searches for a specific word in both upper and lower case.

For example, to search for 'zebra' or 'Zebra', I have created the string `\b(z|Z)(ebra)\b`.

This works, but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Not really, maybe just `\b[z|Z]ebra\b`

Comment: You could use `\b[Zz]ebra\b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't anything much better than you have now. You could drop the parentheses though and simplify it a bit:
`\b[Zz]ebra\b` or `\b([Zz]ebra)\b` if you need a capturing group.